# Polyominos packing into a square

Tags: tiling, polyomino, packing

**Rules of the game:**

- Take a square grid nxn.
- Populate the grid with polyonimoes of area size 1 to area of 9.
- Polyominoes can be any shape.
- There must be one each of every size polyomino in every row and column of the grid and only once each.
- You can use as many of each size polyomino that you wish.

[image: polyominoes up to size 5]

The image show some shapes of the smaller polyominoes

The question is

> **what is the smallest nxn square that can fit all of the above?**

How many of each size polyomino is required?

Comment: Do you need to fill the square with polyominoes or is empty space allowed between the pieces?

Comment: Empty space is allowed but a complete packing would be preferable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's establish a lower bound on $n$.

> A polyomino with an area of $k$ squares can cover at most $k+1$ rows and columns. This is because a polyomino is a connected region, and if you add a square to the polyomino to enlarge it, it may expand but only in at most one direction, encroaching on just one additional row or column. A monomino covers $2$ ($1$ row and $1$ column) so a $k$-omino covers at most $k+1$ rows/columns.
>
>  For each $k\in\{1,2,...,9\}$, we need the $k$-ominos to cover the $2n$ rows/columns of the $n\times n$ board. Each one covers at most $k+1$, so we need at least $\lceil \frac{2n}{k+1} \rceil$ of them. Adding together their total area, we find that it exceeds $n^2$, the area of the board, for all $n<15$.
>
>  So we have a lower bound of $n=15$. Here is a table of the amounts in this case, and it turns out that the pieces would have to completely fill the board:
>
> ```
>    k  #pcs  Area
>    1  15    15
>    2  10    20
>    3  8     24
>    4  6     24
>    5  5     25
>    6  5     30
>    7  4     28
>    8  4     32
>    9  3     27
>            ---
>     Total: 225
> ```

This initial lower bound can be improved upon.

> With a large polyomino you have some leeway in how many rows/columns it will cover. For example, the 9-omino can cover just 6 rows/columns if it is a 3x3 square, or 10 rows/columns when it is straight. Smaller polyominoes are less flexible.
>  The domino always covers exactly 3 rows/columns. For this puzzle that means that $2n$ is a multiple of $3$, and hence that $n$ is a multiple of $3$.
>  Similarly, the tromino always covers exactly 4 rows/columns, whichever shape it is. This means that $2n$ must be a multiple of $4$, and hence that $n$ is even.
>  Given these last two requirements, the smallest board size that might work is $n=18$.

Here is a solution which is highly likely to be non-optimal. I hope others can find a solution that attains the lower bound established above.

> Here $n=24$. It is easy to use a $k$-omino to cover all the rows/columns of a $3\times3$ or $2\times2$ square. I combine some of these so as to make four kinds of $6\times6$ square such that each row/column is covered by the $k$-ominos being used. I then combine these four types of $6\times6$ square so that each row/column has one of each type.
>  [image: Solution for n=24]

**Edit:**
Retudin has found a solution that does attain the lower bound, and which is therefore optimal.

Comment: I was about to publish a study on the lower limit using the same reasoning. However, we can increase your lower limit of 1 because rot13(bar bs lbhe 3 cbylzvab bs fvmr 9 vf n fgenvtgu yvar (be lbh pnag' pbire gur jubyr 15k15 tevq). Va guvf pnfr, gurer ner bayl 6 fcnprf yrsg ba guvf yvar, juvpu vf abg  rabhtu gb cynpr gur erznvavat 8 cbylzvab. Urapr ybjre yvzvg vf ng yrnfg 16)

Comment: @franckvivien You can use L-shaped pieces, and a size 9 polyomino in an L shape can cover 5 rows and 5 columns, so three can cover all. I don't see why one of them would need to be straight.

Comment: you're perfectly right. I had in mind covering the grid using  one horizontal p9 + one vertical p9 + one L, but of course the straight lines can be replaced by L! So I am ok with your minimum grid

Answer (score 5):

The optimal answer:

> Each row and column must be uniquely covered by each size
> - the size 2 pieces always cover 3 (row+column)s.
> - the size 3 pieces always cover 4 (row+column)s.
> Thus row+column must be a multiple of 12.
> - A 6x6 square cannot contaim all sizes since that needs at least 45 squares
> - A 12x12 square cannot cover every row+column since that needs at least 3 of every size (135 squares) and at least one extra of size1-6 (+21 together >144)
>  - A 18x18 square is possible - and thus optimal (see picture)

> [image]

> 18x18 cannot be fully packed
>  - The solution above has 9 holes and only the fives and sixes can be more densely packed (5 i.s.o. 6 (row +column)'s )
>  - Since the 1,2 and 3s cannot be less dense packed, we need at least 3 extra 5s or 6s.
>  - 8 fives or sixes are thus needed which use at least 40 rows+columns.
>  - we have only 36, so overlap cannot be avoided

> 24x24 or greater can also not be fully packed
>  - the most dense packing (3x3 for 7,8,9 3x2 for 6,5 etc) has:
>  (9+8+7)n/6 + (6+5)n/5 = (4+3)n/4 +2n/3+ n/2 blocks (and nxn/4 places)
>  (where n is rows+columns.)
>
> Which means the following must be true (4+ 2.2 + 1.75 + 2/3 + 0.5) > rows/2
> thus rows < 18.233.

Comment: You have rows/columns that contain more than one polyomino of the same size. For example in the 1,4,9 square, the two size 9 polyominos both cover the middle two rows/columns.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis : thx, fixed

Comment: I have improved the lower bound, which proves that your answer is optimal.

Comment: I found the same proof (added) and added a full packing is impossible argument, so it is really optimal